# Currency symbol position

Tags: web-services, localization, countries

In my program I have to display prices for different countries. To do this, I generate a special formatting class for each country (using open web services):

```
public class Country
{
    ...
    // autogenerated with T4
    public static readonly List<Country> Countries = new List<Country>
    {
        new Country
        {
            CountryCode = "us",
            CallingCode = "1",
            CountryName = "United States",
            CountryCodeNumeric = "840",
            CountryCodeA3 = "usa",
            CurrencySymbol = "$",
            Continent = "NA",
            ContinentName = "North America",
            Capital = "Washington",
            CurrencyCode = "USD",
            ...
        },
    ...
```

But I also need currency symbol location to display prices properly. For example: I can place currency symbol before or after the price: `8.40 €` and `€ 8.40`.

Is there any web service or another reliable source, which I can use to get currency symbol positions?

Comment: The standard numeric format string is not enough? It has a currency format... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx . You would just need to know the culture for each curency. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky2chs3h.aspx

Comment: The very first question is why on the earth you want to format this for web service. Usually web services are to transmit locale-independent data. You should definitely format this with the client code.